# How to check multiple host name in systemd unit condition

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

I'm trying to make a systemd service have a conditional start based on multiple hostname pattern.

I've tried this without luck:

```
root@linkbox-BI034415:/# systemctl cat mcbapp
# /lib/systemd/system/myservice.service
[Unit]
Description=My Service
Wants=another.service
After=another.service
ConditionHost=HostOne*|HostTwo*
Also tried
ConditionHost={HostOne*,HostTwo*}


[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/myenv
ExecStart=/opt/bin/my-apps
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;dr:

```
ConditionHost=|HostOne*
ConditionHost=|HostTwo*
```

---

You can easily check your conditions with `systemd-analyze`. That should speed up your testing.

Here's an example where I am using `ConditionHost` on my own machine (`stewbian`).

Here, I succeed with an exact match.

```
$ systemd-analyze condition ConditionHost=stewbian
test.service: ConditionHost=stewbian succeeded.
Conditions succeeded
```

Here, I succeed with a globbed match

```
$ systemd-analyze condition ConditionHost=stew*
test.service: ConditionHost=stew* succeeded.
Conditions succeeded.
```

Here, I correctly failed with a bad match

```
$ systemd-analyze condition ConditionHost=machine2
test.service: ConditionHost=machine2
```

So first, we could say that your test could work with `ConditionHost=Host*`, but I suspect you want to be more precise.

---

From [`man systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conditions%20and%20Asserts):

> If multiple conditions are specified, the unit will be executed if all of them apply (i.e. a logical AND is applied).

Therefore, multiple conditions should be on separate lines, but they will be AND'd, so it will fail

```
$ systemd-analyze condition "ConditionHost=machine2" "ConditionHost=stewbian"
test.service: ConditionHost=stewbian succeeded.
test.service: ConditionHost=machine2 failed.
Conditions failed.
```

But the man page continues:

> Condition checks can use a pipe symbol ("|") after the equals sign ("Condition…=|…"), which causes the condition to become a triggering condition. If at least one triggering condition is defined for a unit, then the unit will be started if at least one of the triggering conditions of the unit applies and all of the regular (i.e. non-triggering) conditions apply.

Therefore, use `ConditionHost=|` on each condition and the conditions will be OR'd:

```
$ systemd-analyze condition "ConditionHost=|machine2" "ConditionHost=|stewbian"
test.service: ConditionHost=|stewbian succeeded.
test.service: ConditionHost=|machine2 failed.
Conditions succeeded.
```

You can also include the globs:

```
$ systemd-analyze condition \
    "ConditionHost=|stew*" \
    "ConditionHost=|machine*"
test.service: ConditionHost=|machine* failed.
test.service: ConditionHost=|stew* succeeded.
Conditions succeeded.
```

In your file, use:

```
ConditionHost=|HostOne*
ConditionHost=|HostTwo*
```

---

I can see what you were trying to do.  The [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#ConditionHost=) *do say*:

> This either takes a hostname string (**optionally with shell style globs**) which is tested against the locally set hostname ...

If we look at [`man 7 glob`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) we read:

> A string is a wildcard pattern if it contains one of the characters '?', '*', or '['.  Globbing is the operation that expands a wildcard pattern into the list of pathnames matching the pattern.

In this definition neither `|` nor `{...}` are considered globs.  While `{...}` may be considered a common `bash` glob, systemd isn't bash and doesn't use that definition.